# C++11 initializing std::vector of std::shared_ptr in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-semantics

I have a typedef of a vector of std::shared_ptr like so:

```
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> > FooMap;
```

Then I have a `Bar` class with a `FooMap` member declared like:

```
FooMap _foos;
```

The `Bar` constructor looks like:

```
Bar::Bar(FooMap& foos) : _foos(foos) {}
```

I've also tried:

```
Bar::Bar(FooMap& foos) : _foos(std::move(foos)) {}
```

Neither will compile. I get:

```
error: no match for call to 
‘(FooMap {aka     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >}) (FooMap&)’
```

or:

```
error: no match for call to 
‘(FooMap {aka std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >})
(std::remove_reference<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >&>::type)
```

respectively.

When I call the `Bar` constructor I get the FooMap from another class:

`FooMap foo = baz1.foos();`

then

`Bar bar(foo);`

The `Baz` class `foos()` method is:

`const FooMap& Baz::foos() const { return myFooMap; }`

Move constructors I'm still trying to figure out but I definitely can't understand why the first one doesn't just use the std::vector copy constructor.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Rvalues don't bind to non-const lvalue references.

Comment: The copy constructor would be fine though. He doesn't show the call site though so it's impossible to know if the constructor is the problem or *calling* the constructor.

Comment: Can't reproduce. it compiles:  http://ideone.com/szEpOt

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of this working perfectly fine:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
};

typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> > FooMap;

class Bar {
    public:
        Bar(FooMap & foos):
            foos_(foos)
        {}

    private:
        FooMap foos_;
};

int main() {
    FooMap f = { std::make_shared<Foo>(), std::make_shared<Foo>() };
    Bar b(f);
}
```

Comment: Instead of a snarky comment could you tell me what's wrong with the design? I'm always willing to learn.